# CKAN UI to consume CKAN API

Tags: ckan

I'm new to CKAN.

There are two different CKAN with 2 different domain/IPs, CKAN-A and CKAN-B.
I know there are CKAN-API for create/update package/ekstras.

With postman, it's solved, just need to hit that endpoints. But I need to do that in UI way. So:

```
CKAN-A post create package to CKAN-B (e.g. id: xx001)

CKAN-B edit that package and update to CKAN-A
```

All with UI approach, not by postman/other tools. Can we do that in CKAN? How?

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1: Wouldn't it be a good idea to have two CKAN servers share one database?

Solution 2: Create a CKAN Extension to change the behavior of the package creation and modification UI.
Your CKAN Extension can update the other CKAN server using CKAN's API.
Please refer to the manual (https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/extensions/index.html)

WARNING: Write a CKAN Extenion is Very difficult.

Comment: No, there is not one database. CKAN A with DB itself, so do with CKAN B.